# login authentification token php .. stuck

Tags: php

When the user registers an account, a table is created with columns; userid and token.  This is because if the user checks remember me when logging in on different computers, each computer has a different token.

register.php

```
//user specific table created    
$create = $connectdb->prepare("CREATE TABLE `user-:username` (userid INT, token varchar(200)");
                        $executequery = $create->execute(array("username"=>$username));
```

Here is a snippet of login.php; I create the token, store the token in a cookie and insert the token to that user specific table

```
  if($remember==1) {
                            $token = md5(uniqid('',true));
                            setcookie('token',$token,time()+60*60*24*365);

                            $rememberquery = $connectdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `user-:username` VALUES ('',:username,:token)");
                            $rememberquery->execute(array(":username"=>$username,":token"=>$token));
$_SESSION['username'][0] = $username;       
$_SESSION['username'][1] = $userid;                 
                            }
```

Now i'm stuck(assuming i have done the previous correctly). When/How do i check the cookie token to the database token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proper authentication is hard to do correctly so, you have to play a little hacker from time to time in order to get things mostly right. First of all, you should read [Session Management Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet) and owasp page in general.

After this lecture you should know the dos and donts of session management. But if you need a remember me cheat sheet ;) it should go like this:

- Value should be either completely random, or cryptographically strong(which can be tricky)
- Should be validated upon recive
- Never ever ever trust in what you get in a cookie, so storing username in a cookie is a very very very bad idea, if it is not followed by proper validation
- If session expires create new one, populate it with data from your table, and voila,
- If you need to persist something, use database not a cookie cookies are bad and not trustworthy ;)

Also a fine publication is by microsoft [Threats and countermeasures](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24696) , it can help you a lot.